# Settings the splash screen in one resolution causes the others to disappear in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to setup the splash screens at multiple resolutions in the new XCode 5.0 but every time I import one image resolution (at the exact size), the previous imported image is removed from the list...

Any work around to this strange behaviour? (bug?)

Comment: I had similar problem..Leo's answers helped me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using the assets catalog feature of Xcode 5? If not, you should. You specify in your target settings to use the entry in the asset catalog, and you just drag and drop the different launch images. It's really easy.

[image]